# Hystrix and OSGI bundle

Tags: osgi, bundle, hystrix

I have used org.apache.servicemix.bundles.hystrix dependency to bundle Hystrix as OSGI bundle. However, I'm facing this issue:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: [828]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.netflix.hystrix; version="[1.5.0,2.0.0)"
```

Can someone help me on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that the bundle you try to install and resolve requires a certain package and that there is no bundle that offers this package.

So in you case the package **com.netflix.hystrix** is missing. This means that you either do not have the hystrix bundle installed or you installed a version that does not match the version range **[1.5.0,2.0.0)**.